# Is having a primary key in a database table really necessary?

Tags: sql, database

I know this question has been asked a lot of times, but please, explain it on this example.

So... I have 2 tables: Users and Groups

```
Users(ID, Name...)
Groups(ID, UserID[FK], GroupName)
```

Every user can have multiple records(groups) in the Groups table.

Ok, so why do I really need the ID field in the Groups table?
Every SQL I do is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE UserID = ...
```

Also, a user must not have duplicate groups, so there will never be 2 exact rows in the table.

So, what is the ID field used for?

Comment: Almost every ORM requires a primary key, so think about how youar database is going to be used.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use a single integer column as your primary key - you could just define your primary key as `UserID` and `GroupName`.

Why would you want to use a primary key at all?

1. Depending on your DBMS, the records in the table will be organized by the primary key, making lookups by that key the fastest possible. Defining a primary key is very easy to do. For the tiny investment involved, you get a massive increase in performance and scalability.
2. Nearly all DBMSes enforce uniqueness of the primary key. You said that a user cannot have the same group twice. Be defining the primary key as `UserID` and `GroupName`, you can guarantee at the database level (without any additional code) that that assumption will always be true.

Comment: OK, but I still haven't got an answer why do I need a primary key at all? Can I just index the Groups table by UserID without having a primary key?

Answer (score 2):

Having a primary key in a database table is not a requirement, but usually it's a good idea. Imagine you have a million records and want to find UserID 532,395. Without an index, the database will have to search through the entire file until it finds the record. With an index it only has to search through a few records.

In your case I would index/key the Groups table by UserID so you can rapidly find all groups a given user is in. You could have a primary key of (UserID,GroupName) or an auto incrementing row number.

Comment: Primary keys are typically unique. If you set the UserID as primary on the group table, then no user could have more than one group

Comment: You are correct - I was thinking of an index and have edited my response.

Comment: Ok, I understand the index part. Also understand the primary key can be made from 2 fields, but I still don't understand why do I need a primary key at all? I can differ my rows with UserID field...

Comment: One thing having a primary key of (UserID,GroupName) will do is prevent you from having multiple identical entries.

Answer (score 1):

It takes less time to do something well than to do it twice.

When you design a database, not only do you have to satisfy current needs, you should anticipate future needs.  For example, you stated a current requirement of, "Also, a user must not have duplicate groups".  That's fine, but what if it changed?

I would go with 3 tables myself.  Groups would have GroupID as the PK, plus GroupName as a field, plus any other fields I deemed appropriate.  Users would have a similar structure.

My third table would be UserGroups.  It would have a composite primary key consisting of UserID, GroupID, and maybe some other fields depending on how I envisioned current and future requirements.

Also, I find that putting CreatedWhen, CreatedBy, LastUpdatedWhen, LastUpdatedBy in all tables is often worth the time and effort.

Finally, when you do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE UserID = ...
```

I'll do this:

```
select JustTheFieldsINeed
from Users join UserGroups using (UserId)
join Groups using (GroupId)
where UserId = something
and other conditions are met.
```

While your approach will entail less work at first, if I am told 3 years from now that users can now belong to more that one group, I can simply say, "Yes sir, 3 bags full sir", and then take a nap.

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is not normally mandatory, though it is usually recommended. If the amount of data on a table is very small a primary key will not improve performance as the whole table will be read every time it is accessed. However with most small size tables a primary key will make read performance quicker.

For tables with no primary key or unique keys you may encounter a few problems:

1. how can you identify records. You must be able to distinguish one
   record from another in order to run the correct SQL statement.
2. If your table has millions of records, your select statement to look
   for a particular record will take forever to run since you are not
   using a primary key.

In your `users` table use `ID` as primary key

Comment: What is a "normal size" table?